# What is the best way to manage small blocks of content on my home page?

Tags: custom-post-types, cms, design, customization

Excuse the newbie question.

I have a home page that has 2 sections on it. None of these sections are the 'blog' which is in another section of the site. I suppose I'm looking for another way of content managing these sections.

The first is a 'what we do' section. It has three paragraphs that are limited to say 200 words. e.g:

1. Title then 200 words
2. Title then 200 words
3. Title then 200 words

There are no other pages associated with each point. I want each to be available in the backend for editing.

The second section 'Example Work' consists of 6 images with a small caption underneath each one. How would I go about content managing each one of these?

From reading around, I found 'Custom Post Types' but that seems like quite a bit of work for something that would be potentially quite simple. This must have been done a thousand times before. Also this is potentially a 'module' - but again I'm not sure.

I'm not necessarily looking for code (feel free to include though) but a high level description of the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/

This is easiest in my opinion. It's like managing custom post types but with the custom field functionality. Simply first create a group 'what we do', then add each title as a text field ( there's a button when creating groups that says 'text' just hit it 3 times and name each whatever). 'Example Work' can be your second group, where you'll add 6 images ( wp should add caption automatically) . The two don't have to be separate groups unless you want the two areas to show up for different categories or ect.

The fields will show in the post editor where you'll have to place the shortcodes in the main editor ( save this a a template so you don't have to do it over and over), then just add the content to the custom fields boxes.

Pretty much like adding recipe fields to a page titled " Cooking".

Comment: Thanks Donna. I would upvote you but I can't !